# What is the right way to create a Buffer to hold ByteStrings in Haskell

Tags: networking, haskell, arrays

I am trying to create a buffer in memory, that I can use in order to send `ByteString`s from a server to a client over a socket. I want it to be mutable, so I can reuse it.

The reason I want to do this is because sending lazy `ByteString`s directly causes lots of objects to be created for every server response and slows the server down due to excessive garbage collection (40% spent in GC).

I was looking into `IOUArray` but that will only work for `Int`, `Word32` and such, but not for `ByteString`.

The other option I'm looking into is to create an `Array Int (IORef ByteString)` - each ByteString would have to have same size, but am not sure if this is the right way to go.

I looked into lots of documentations online, but they either address `IOArray` or `IORef`, but never an Array of ByteStrings.

I greatly appreciate any pointers, how to go about this or where to look for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you will like the [blaze-builder](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-builder-0.3.1.0) package.